# why does <span> opens a new line block?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular-material

I want to make id, names and countries to be all inline

I wrapped them in `<span>` as guided [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)

but yet I see each of them in a new row-block.

```
<md-card-title-text>
    <span class="md-headline">ID: {{voice.id}}</span>
    <span class="md-subhead">Name: {{voice.name}}</span>
    <span style="padding-right: 10em" class="md-subhead">Countries: {{voice.conditionFromUi.countries === null ? "None" :  voice.conditionFromUi.countries}}</span>
    <span class="md-subhead">User flag: {{voice.conditionFromUi.userFlag === null ? "None" : voice.conditionFromUi.userFlag}}</span>
    <span class="md-subhead">From date: {{voice.conditionFromUi.fromDate === null ? "None" : voice.conditionFromUi.fromDate}}
          ---> To date: {{voice.conditionFromUi.toDate === null ? "None" : voice.conditionFromUi.toDate}} </span>
</md-card-title-text>
```

I have tries this as well buy yet the sub-titles are in new line

```
 <md-card-title-text>
                    <span >ID: {{voice.id}}</span>
                    <span >Name: {{voice.name}}</span>
                    <span style="padding-right: 10em" class="md-subhead">Countries: {{voice.conditionFromUi.countries === null ? "None" :  voice.conditionFromUi.countries}}</span>
```

and

```
            <md-card-title-text>
                <span style="padding-right: 10em; display:block" class="md-headline">ID: {{voice.id}}</span>
                <span class="md-subhead">Name: {{voice.name}}</span>
                <span style="padding-right: 10em; display:block" class="md-subhead">Countries: {{voice.conditionFromUi.countries === null ? "None" :  voice.conditionFromUi.countries}}</span>
                <span class="md-subhead">User flag: {{voice.conditionFromUi.userFlag === null ? "None" : voice.conditionFromUi.userFlag}}</span>
```

Comment: please provide additional css

Comment: Probably it's because of the class you're using in your `<span>` that makes it open a new line

Comment: Your CSS classes .md-headline .md-subhead etc should have a "display:block"

Comment: @Pierre-AndréVullioud I have tried this as well (see my updated question)

Comment: @EladBenda2 its because you're using `md-card-title-text` as a parent and it has defined as `flex` in `angular material css` with `flex-direction: column;` viz why each of its child element will be visible as column(i.e. above each other as stack or column) not as a row(i.e. side by side), you have to change its `css` to `flex-direction: row;` look for another option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without providing some css it's hard to tell what exactly is causing this, but it's most likely something in one of the classes on the span elements that's causing it, potentially `display: block`.

Try setting the span elements to `display: inline-block`

```
md-card-title-text span {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```